# No network from minimum net install

Tags: networking, systemd, dhcp, dhclient, dhcpd

- I did a minimum net install, but my new system is not starting the network automatically -- No IP address with my `eth0` device.
- I installed `dhclient` package myself but that doesn't help. I thought it should have been taken care of by the post-install of the `dhclient` package.
- Searching for the answer myself, I found [this page](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=154844), hinting that I have to write such systemd unit for myself.
- If so, I have to first understand what's [systemd unit activate vs enable](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/302261/systemd-unit-activate-vs-enable), whereas previously in init5, all I need to do is to install a service package and its post-install will take care of enabling the service itself.

All these have been way too complicated than it should, I believe. Somebody help please.

**UPDATE:**

OK, maybe the reason is that this is a minimum net install, and I don't have all those things required. Here is more info:

```sh
$ ip a
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST> mtu 1500 qdisc noop state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:0c:29:56:d8:4c brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    altname enp2s1
    altname ens33

$ ls /etc/netplan
ls: cannot access '/etc/netplan': No such file or directory

$ sudo service NetworkManager status
Unit NetworkManager.service could not be found.

$ ls /usr/lib/systemd/system/dhcpcd.service
ls: cannot access '/usr/lib/systemd/system/dhcpcd.service': No such file or directory
```

But still, if I run `dhclient` myself manually, I *will* get IP under such minimum install. I.e., the NetworkManager is not absolutely necessary, I hope. And I hope there is a fix for situation like this, whether using `dhcpcd` or `dhclient`.

Comment: What OS & release are you asking about?

Comment: The 20.04 LTS @guiverc

Comment: Please edit your question to show the result of these terminal commands: `ip a` and also: `cat /etc/netplan/*.yaml` and finally: `sudo service NetworkManager status | grep Active` I doubt that a post on an Arch forum that is nine years old is valid here.

Comment: Thanks @chili555, basically, this is a minimum net install, and I don't have all those things you requested. See my updated OP.

Answer (score 2):

You don't have network-manager installed, so your host cannot obtain an IP address.  You have two choices: 1) manually configure the eth0 interface in /etc/network/interfaces or 2) install network-manager

1. Manually Configure

`cd /etc/network/`

`nano interfaces`

Add these lines at the bottom:

`auto eth0`

`iface eth0 inet dhcp`

2. Install Network Manager

`sudo apt install network-manager`

After whichever approach you choose, reboot the machine.  Do not do both, as network-manager will ignore what's in interfaces once enabled.  Tested and confirmed Ubuntu 20.x and Debian Bullseye.

Comment: Third option would be Installing the `dhcpcd`, and it got my IP fixed, so the NetworkManager is not absolutely necessary. But I'll upvote for you.

Comment: @xpt ideally, a static configuration in interfaces would better than all three, especially if this is public facing as you don’t want to just blindly accept dhcp server solicitations … but yeah that works too, since it is the dhcp portion of network manager, but likely that’s less skinny than a simple configuration if space and minimalism is your intent.  ;)

Comment: I believe that /etc/network/interfaces is deprecated in 20.04 in favor of netplan.

Comment: This is legacy fix for sure, but it’s for a minimal install, still works, and is very elegant.

Comment: Also, interfaces is only deprecated on desktop Ubuntu, not server Ubuntu and/or Debian.

Answer (score 1):

Installing the `dhcpcd` got my IP, but only for IPv6, no IPv4 address.
So I'm closing this one and opening another one for that instead.